# Creating a Panel of Scatterplots in R (not a full matrix)

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a panel of 3 scatterplots, all with the same Y axis and each with a different X axis, on different scales. I am visualizing 3 stacked scatterplots. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with ggplot2. Remember that the data needs to be turned to long in this case, with a variable indicating which of the three panels the data goes to (here, the variable "cat" indicates this):

```
mydf <- data.frame(y = rnorm(300), 
                   x = c(rnorm(100, 100), rnorm(100, 50), rnorm(100, 200)), 
                   cat = c(rep("A", 100), rep("B", 100), rep("C", 100)))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(cat), scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

EDIT: with the facets laid out vertically with the same axes throughout:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(cat), ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This was really helpful! How would I go around rotating it so the X is on the bottom (and the same) and the plots are stacked vertically?

Comment: Try to modify the `facet_wrap()` part

  `facet_wrap(vars(cat),ncol=1, scales = "fixed")`